# Need some HTML element with HTMLAgilityPack in C# - how to do it?

Tags: c#, html, parsing, html-agility-pack

I have the following scenario:

```
<a href="test.com">Some text <b>is bolded</b> some is <b>not</b></a>
```

Now, how do I get the "test.com" part and the anchor of the text, without having the bolded parts?

Comment: Are you looking to extract "Some text is bolded some is not" (the text of the anchor without formatting markup) or "Some text some is" (content within markup removed)?

Comment: I need to extract the link within the anchor and the whole text without formatting mark-up. That would be "Some text is bolded some is not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the following markup:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="test.com">Some text <b>is bolded</b> some is <b>not</b></a>
</body>
</html>
```

You could perform the following:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.Load("test.html");
        var anchor = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//a");
        Console.WriteLine(anchor.Attributes["href"].Value);
        Console.WriteLine(anchor.InnerText);
    }
}
```

prints:

```
test.com
Some text is bolded some is not
```

Of course you probably wanna adjust your `SelectSingleNode` XPath selector by providing an unique id or a classname to the anchor you are trying to fetch:

```
// assuming <a href="test.com" id="foo">Some text <b>is bolded</b> some is <b>not</b></a>
var anchor = doc.GetElementbyId("foo");
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. I did a bit of a hack on the HTML to get the text I wanted. I stripped out the link and then I gave it to the LoadHTML method of the HtmlDocument. It did the trick. Unfortunately I couldn't use the GetElementbyId, so the hack did its job OK.